# Ethics of reputation-hunting

Tags: discussion

I came to StackOverflow with a question I knew would be difficult and specialized. As soon as I found out about the bounty system I went to work collecting reputation so that at 48 hours my reputation would be over 300 and I could offer that as a bounty, if my question did not already have an acceptable answer. I have always tried to be a net contributor to any forum I use to get answers to my questions, but I was definitely working to gain reputation during the 48 hours from posting my question to it becoming eligible for a bounty.

I did not see anything obviously unethical about, in effect, trading my time and existing skills for attention to my question in an area I'm learning.

However, I've since seen references to being a "reputation-whore". Was deliberate reputation-hunting with the intent of being in a position to offer a bounty against local standards?

Comment: As I understand the answers so far, it is not so much a matter of intent than of means. Trying to collect reputation by productive means, such as answering an unanswered question or writing a genuinely better answer, is fine. Trying to collect reputation by non-productive means, such as angling for up-votes and acceptances, is not so good.

Comment: "Trying to collect reputation by productive means, such as answering an unanswered question or writing a genuinely better answer, is fine." **Ab-so-lute-ly!**

Comment: This is the whole point of rep: encouraging you to be productive :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is nothing wrong in answering questions and get reputation for it. 
And there is nothing wrong in spending your reputaion on bounty. In fact you are giving your reputation to others in exchange for their time. That is what the bounty system is for.

A "*reputation-whore*" would be asking the OP to accept your answer and/or upvote it.

Comment: @threeFourOneSixOneThree, ok so do you "educate" those users out of the kindness of your heart, or because you want the filthy lucre? :)

Comment: Regarding the statement of being an rep-street-woman i disagree - some users are not aware of the fact that if you really tried to help them and had several exchanges, that at least an upvote is something like "Thanks for trying".
@Benjol pure kindness ;-)

Comment: @threeFourOneSixOneThree: No, an upvote is not a "Thanks", it's an "It's useful".

Answer (score 3):

As long as your answers are useful, you are not trying to guess the answer, and you are not repeating what already said from another answer, your answers are perfectly fine.

Being able to gain 200 points in a day is not a signal that you are only interested only on gaining reputation. The fact the badge you get for that is a bronze badge probably means it is not that difficult, to get 200 points in a single day.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion if you give an answer that has the quality to be of use (good link, good code exmaple, no false solutions) i consider it to be perfectly fine to get points for that. I would go as far as to say that 10 and 15 points is quite low considering how much time it may take to give a usefull answer.